# Distance Estimation Rational Julia Set

Tags: fractals

I have the following julia set:
$$
f(z)=z\cdot\Omega=z\cdot\left(\sum_{j=1}^A\omega_j(z)^{-1}\right)^{-1}
$$
where
$$
\omega_j(z)=C\prod_{i=0}^{N_j}(z-r_{j,i})
$$
Where $C$ and all the $r_{j,i}$ are complex constants. Depending on what I choose for the $r_{j,i}$ I can approximate any shape in the complex plane. Now I would like to estimate the distance to this julia set. I have done this before for simpler fractals using [DEM/J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set#Using_DEM/J), which states that
$$
\delta(z)= \lim_{k\to+\infty} \dfrac{|z_k|\log|z_k|}{|z_k'|}
$$
**Is this approximation for the distance usable with my julia set?**

I have tried to derive $f(z)$, but the results I'm getting are not correct distance estimations. I have the following for the derivative
$$
(f(z))'=z'\cdot f'(z)=z'\cdot\left(\Omega+z\cdot\Omega^2\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{A}\omega_j'\omega_j^{-2}\right)
$$
where
$$
\omega_j'(z)=C\sum_{i=0}^{N_j}\left(\prod_{k\neq i}^{N_j}z-r_{j,k}\right)
$$
If I understand correctly I should be able to calculate the derivative by doing $z_{k+1}'=f'(z_k)z_k'$.

**Is my derivative of $f(z)$ correct?**

Comment: Are preconditions for distance estimate met? See for example Milnor's Dynamics in One Complex Variable (3rd ed) Appendix H > Let $f : C \to C$ be a rational map with a superattractive fixed point of local degree n at the origin. Assume that the basin of attraction U for this fixed point is connected, simply connected, and contains no other
critical point. Then the Bottcher coordinate of §9 can be defined throughout U [...]

Comment: I can't seem to find a copy of the book you're referencing. Also I don't think I'm well versed enough to truly understand what you mean unless I have something to read into. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, it seems I made a mistake in my code. The distance estimation is not correct, but it isn't discontinuous anymore. It might still be possible to get an accurate distance estimation, but I wouldn't know how.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Mathematics/Derivative